# Python Django: Load Autofield to MySql Table using loaddata

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model with two `DateField` - fields in it, which I dumped to JSON using dumpdata. Now I want to load those fixtures (I am using South) to my MySQL-Database which leads to the following Error:

> CommandError: The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

Does anybody know that problem and the solution to it?

My Database is MySql (version 5.6.12)  and I'm using Django 1.5.1. I used Sqlite before and want to change to MySQL.

Comment: How you are trying to load data?

Comment: I have a migration in where I call call_command("loaddata", "lectures.json") in the forwards-Method

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution - I had to use dumpdata app.model --natural